# When using transformation matrices, how does one convert orientation and scaling from a global frame of reference into a local one?

Tags: c++, matrix, transform, glm-math

*Note: I'm certain I cannot be the first to answer this question. Unfortunately, the answers I need are buried under an avalanche of posts asking how to move coordinates between frames of reference, and other similar but unhelpful problems.*

As part of an ongoing project, I've built a `Transform` object. As one might expect, this is essentially a glorified wrapper around a 4x4 transformation matrix (and various base values), and provides abstracted ways of interacting with position, orientation, and scale, as well as handling parenting to other instances to build complex hierarchies.

I am currently trying to allow the user to set and alter values of child transforms in global terms. Position is straightforward (if I'm doing it right), as this simply involves converting a coordinate from a global frame or reference to a local one.

```
void Transform::setGlobalPosition(const glm::vec3& newPos)
{
    glm::vec4 nlp = glm::vec4(newPos, 1.0f);
    if (m_hasParent) {
        // This gets the parent transform from the Entity-Component System.
        auto& p = p_registry->get<Transform>(m_parent);

        nlp = glm::inverse(p.m_globalTransformM) * nlp;
    }

    setPosition(nlp);
}

void Transform::alterGlobalPosition(const glm::vec3& deltaPos)
{
    glm::vec4 nlp = glm::vec4(m_globalPosition + deltaPos, 1.0f);
    if (m_hasParent) {
        // This gets the parent transform from the Entity-Component System.
        auto& p = p_registry->get<Transform>(m_parent);

        nlp = glm::inverse(p.m_globalTransformM) * nlp;
    }
        setPosition(nlp);
}
```

However, I have absolutely no clue how to accomplish the same for the following.

```
// Transform member functions.
void setGlobalScale(const glm::vec3& newScale);
void alterGlobalScale(const glm::vec3& deltaScale);
void setGlobalOrientation(const glm::quat& newOri);
void alterGlobalOrientation(const glm::quat& deltaOri);
```

Position coordinates are easy, but how does one approach the problem for rotations and scaling? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may get better results asking at https://math.stackexchange.com/ since this problem is entirely mathematical.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have no idea what you mean by that. As the code snippet I've provided demonstrates, it's entirely possible to do so for position, and I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible for orientation and scale. It may require access to the parent transforms, possibly recursively until it reaches the top of the hierarchy, if that's what you mean?